# Akkadian Kašdu, Hebrew Kaśdim (כַּשְׂדִּֽים׃) glossed as "clod-breakers": Is there a clear source for the gloss?

Tags: hebrew, word-choice

I'm aware of the origins of the Chaldeans as a branch of the Arameans who took over southern Mesopotamia. I'm interested in the meaning of the Akkadian and Hebrew words that apparently became attached to them. I frequently see the gloss "clod-breakers," but I can't find any clear source for that gloss.

I've seen Kaśdim כַּשְׂדִּֽים׃ linked to Kesed כֶּ֣שֶׂד meaning "increase." Is that a possible meaning of the Akkadian word?

Ideally, I'm looking for an academic source that I can reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *kašdu(m)* were a native Akkadian word, it would almost certainly have to be related to the common verb [*kašādu(m)*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ka%C5%A1%C4%81dum), which has the basic meaning "to reach (something)" and variety of related and derived meanings.  Indeed, it *is* attested as [the verbal adjective thereof](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ka%C5%A1dum), with meanings including "achieved", "arrived", "conquered", "successful", "sufficient", etc.

However, I'd assume that *Kašdu* (or *Kaldu*, as it's attested in later Akkadian due to a regular sound change) as an ethnonym is probably Aramaic in origin, so looking for an Akkadian etymology is unlikely to yield much insight.  Alas, that's also where I have to stop and leave the rest for someone else to fill in, as my knowledge of Aramaic is extremely limited.

FWIW, [Huehnergard](https://www.academia.edu/234695/2011_A_Grammar_of_Akkadian_3rd_edition_) (2011, 3rd ed., appendix F) lists *kašādu(m)* as having a possible cognate in Ugaritic *kšd* = "to search, reach", but no Hebrew or Aramaic cognates.